# Аналог table(Sql) в Realm Db

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Никак не найти на официальном сайте, что-то похожее.
Задача такова - существует большой список товаров - это основная база, из неё берутся частично товары и создаются закупки, в форме дополнительных списков и их может быть огромное множество. Как мне организовать работу Realm для дополнительных списков, каждый раз создавать новый объект Realm или есть какой-то другой способ? очень прошу помощи.

Answer (score 3):

1. Статически инициализируйте `RealmConfigurations`, лучше всего сделать это в OnCreate Аппликейшена. Таким образом вы будете иметь единственную конфигурацию на приложение.
2. Создайте класс, который будет иметь объект типа `Realm`, и реализован по паттерну DAO - будет иметь CRUD операции, которые будут выполняться через транзакции по типу:

   `public void create(T model) {
       realm.beginTransaction();
       model.setKey(getDAOKey());
       realm.copyToRealm(model);
       realm.commitTransaction();
   }`
3. В данном случае `T` и является объектом, с которым мы работаем, - объектом нашей таблицей, `T` унаследуется от `RealmObject`.

   `abstract public class BaseDao<T extends RealmObject>`

   Таким образом в данном классе вы сможете прописать любой вам нужный метод, без дублирования объекта типа `Realm`.

Полный пример:

```
    abstract public class BaseDao<T extends RealmObject> {
        private Realm realm;
        DatabaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration;

        public BaseDao() {
            databaseConfiguration = DatabaseConfiguration.getInstance();
            databaseConfiguration.setRealmConfiguration();
            this.realm = databaseConfiguration.getRealmInstance();
        }

        public void create(T model) {
            realm.beginTransaction();
            model.setKey(getDAOKey());
            realm.copyToRealm(model);
            realm.commitTransaction();
        }
     }
```